# Android: ndk-build is returning nothing?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm trying to rebuild my Native android project, however all of a sudden, ndk-build decides it doesn't want to, and seems to be sulking on me. 
Here's my output:

```
nathan@nathan-K52F:~/COMBAT/engine/android-build$ android update project -p . -t 1 -s
Updated project.properties
Updated local.properties
Updated file ./proguard-project.txt
nathan@nathan-K52F:~/COMBAT/engine/android-build$ cd jni && ndk-build
nathan@nathan-K52F:~/COMBAT/engine/android-build/jni$ ndk-build
nathan@nathan-K52F:~/COMBAT/engine/android-build/jni$ cd ../
nathan@nathan-K52F:~/COMBAT/engine/android-build$ ndk-build
nathan@nathan-K52F:~/COMBAT/engine/android-build$      //should be erroring here - yet nothing?
```

It however at least tries to build another native project:

```
nathan@nathan-K52F:~/GamePlay/samples/browser/android/jni$ ndk-build
/home/nathan/android-ndk-r8e/build/core/add-application.mk:128: Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-14 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 9 in /home/nathan/GamePlay/samples/browser/android/AndroidManifest.xml    
Android NDK: ERROR:/home/nathan/GamePlay/samples/browser/android/jni/Android.mk:gameplay: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file    
Android NDK: Check that /home/nathan/GamePlay/samples/browser/android/jni/../../../../gameplay/android/obj/local/armeabi/libgameplay.a exists  or that its path is correct   
/home/nathan/android-ndk-r8e/build/core/prebuilt-library.mk:45: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
nathan@nathan-K52F:~/GamePlay/samples/browser/android/jni$
```

The error's are suppose to be there by the way.

I just haven't a clue why it isn't compiling the project I WANT it to compile - I don't think it likes me anymore :L

I'm running on the latest Ubuntu OS, with NDK r8 and JDK 1.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't add my the new files to my makefile to be compiled.